Why did Stalin bother with signed confessions?
Why did Stalin bother having signed confessions beaten out of anyone? I'm reading Simon Montefiore's book Stalin and am curious about the length he went to to get a real signature on faked documents.
Many of Stalin's enemies (real and imagined) ended up in the basement of the Lubyanka having confessions beaten out of them. The charges were largely groundless, the confessions dictated by their interrogators, the names of co-conspirators added by Stalin. In the unlikely event of a trail/hearing there would be little pretence at fairness and the outcome was largely pre-ordained.
I'm trying to understand why Stalin felt the need to bother with a signature? Every other step of the process was a complete fabrication so why bother with getting the victim to actually sign anything? If the signature was important, why not just get it forged?
Who was he trying to kid? The other soviet leaders knew the process was a sham, the court (if there was one) would follow whatever orders they were given and the people (if they got to hear about it) would only know what Pravda or Izvestia printed (often articles by Stalin himself). It's not as if any defence lawyer would ever examine the signature, or a forensics lab analyse the confession or any appeal court would ever question the interrogation.
I can understand the desire to dress-up the overall process as some sort of legitimate legal process, what I can't understand is why bother with a signature? When the rest of the process is a farce, why bother with a real signature?

This is more psychology than history but the answer may be - himself. If the ink is real, it means all the charges are real too and Stalin's conscience is clear.

@SPavel There may also some psychological aspects inside the victims head as well - in signing they are accepting their role in the whole show trial package and indicates to all involved their intention to stay on script, and that they know the consequences for straying. All useful tools if your job is facilitating smooth conduct of show trials.

Agreeing with @SPavel. All I can really say historically is that engaging in this kind of political justification theater was definitely in character. Churchill documented that the big political Nazi show trials at the end of the war were done at Stalin's insistence too. The question of why strongmen/despots/tyrants behave like this is perhaps a better Politics question.

Some people were acquitted at Nuremberg, which means that they were not like Stalin's 'trials'.

Don't you think that was because justice merely being done was open to so much more criticism than justice being seen to be done?
That there was no justice alters that comparison not one whit.

The context in which to look at confessions is not so much the legal proceedings of a trial, but the ritual and political practice of Criticism and Self-Criticism (Критика и самокритика) that was part of Bolshevik party doctrine since the late 1920s.
The Bolshevik relationship with legal forms is not very clear. On one hand, early theories very much stressed the importance of pure force and terror, giving trials a role of asserting the interests of the "masses" in a completely partisan way, with fairness having no role at all. On the other hand, there always was a layer of procedures that had its root in the tradition of law and judgement.
To understand what was going on, it is central to look at the role of confessions, and their role as the most extreme form of self-criticism. While originally criticism and self-criticism was meant to be a means of collective self-improvement, of tackling real-world problems by openly identifying their root causes, it quickly changed to a game of blaming anyone for any imagined ideological shortcoming, and of throwing oneself at the mercy of the party, vying for forgiveness.
There have been a number explanations, and they range from comparing confessions to the catholic practice of confessionals, to public subjection as a ritual of establishing hierarchical order. Whatever the best of them is, at its core is that the guilty confesses his errors himself. That he is forced to do so, even with extreme measures, is not so important as the ritual of saying it and giving the party the satisfaction of geting their superiority confirmed.

The German Wikipedia article cites a number of academic treaties on the phenomenon, and there is one available online as an incomplete Google Books preview:

Lorenz Erren: „Selbstkritik“ und Schuldbekenntnis. Kommunikation und Herrschaft unter Stalin,. München 2008

The comparison with christian practices is explored for example in

Klaus-Georg Riegel: Rituals of Confession within Communities of virtuosi: An Interpretation of the Stalinist Criticism and Self-criticism in the Perspective of Max Weber’s Sociology of Religion. In: Totalitarian Movements and Political Religions 1(2000), S. 16–42.
researchgate.net provides a download link for a .doc version.



Authority figures may organize show trials featuring public confessions when they are faced with deep rooted contradictions within the social order and want to increase their legitimacy, delegitimize defendants, and justify increased social control in society. An analysis of the court report of the Moscow Show Trials found that these public confessions frame conflicts rooted in contradictions within the social order as acts of deviance that can be resolved with additional social control. The public confessions accomplished this using four main themes: establishing credibility, labeling the defendants as deviant, endorsing the power holder, and demonstrating closure.

The Role of Public Confessions in Show Trials: An Analysis of the Moscow Show Trials, Stephanie K. Decker

that explains the desire for a public confession and a show trial, but doesn't really explain the requirement for a genuine signature - it's not as if the public are ever going to be in a position to check it's genuine.

@ConanTheGerbil - it has nothing to do with whether the public could check. It has everything to do with being sure everything is done 'properly' and 'orderly' and 'by the book'. Never underestimate how insisting on following all the rules perfectly can assuage any feelings of doubt.

The importance of the veneer of legitimacy was also Iyad Al-Bagdhadi's explanation for why strongmen ("Tyrants") continue to pretend to have elections and laws as well.

@ConanTheGerbil: The show of legitimacy makes it easier for people who know that the regime is not legitimate to carry on behaving as if it is. That's a lot safer for them, and influences their neighbours to behave similarly. Getting people to control themselves is a lot easier than doing it by force.
